# Postfix - how to set a message ID?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, sendmail

I have multiple applications using one Postfix instance connecting through SMTP. Some clients set a message ID and some don't.

What I'm trying to do is to let Postfix set its own unique message ID, either for any message it processes or for those that don't have a message ID set. The final result should be that Postfix sends only messages with message ID.

Can anyone please advise me on how to set a unique message ID using Postfix in order to not send out emails without message IDs anymore?

Comment: As I understand Postfix by default adds missing `Message-ID:`.  Are you **SURE** your Postfix sends/relays messages without appending missing` Message-ID:`?

Comment: @AnFi yes I am: There are plenty of messages in the `mail.log` without message IDs.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed behavior before postfix-2.6.  Defaults has been changed most likely to stop messing with "signature headers".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is controlled by the [`always_add_missing_headers` setting](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_add_missing_headers).

By default Postfix will only do that for clients for which it would rewrite (address) headers anyway. You can enable it unconditionally, but first verify that the messages are not (DKIM)-signed in a way that you want to (but cannot, with added headers) preserve.

Newly generated message IDs will contain your configured hostname (`Message-ID: <queueID@myhostname>`)

---

That being said, rather fix/replace the client software instead. If the client cannot be trusted to follow the spec enough to even just generate mandatory headers, who says that by patching up one known issue you are not just more likely missing other interoperability problems that are only evident at certain relays outside your control?