# postfix-How can I discard emails without message-id?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

Some users send smtp emails by postfix.
But there emails have no header Message-ID.
I want to reject them or discard them.
I tried to modify header_checks, but the file filter headers line by line.It can't filter emails without header Message-ID.
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`always_add_missing_headers` feature](https://serverfault.com/questions/1106397/)? You might be content with just editing malformed messages, and extracting the list of offending users from logs later on: The postfix-added header will look like `Message-ID: <queueID@mailserver.hostname.example>` whereas compliant users will add Message-ID: <TimestampOrRnd@maildomain.example>.

Comment: I have tried it.I used post fix docker image.I modified it to yes.But I can't get event logs any more.

Comment: Should i modify other params at the same time?